# Nexus 4 wrong time zone

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

My nexus 4 is showing the wrong time zone. Every single time i turn the automatic time zone and the automatic date & time on, my timezone switches to eastern daylight time (-04:00) but i live in Eastern standard time (-05:00). When i turn both on it becomes the 'right' time but i know that it really isn't since it says -04:00 but it still shows my time. For example, my time here would be say 12:00 A.M on my computer clock but then on my phone if i set it to eastern standard time it would show 11:00 P.M instead of 12:00 A.M . its hard to explain but then when i turn it all off and i change it manually to the right time it works perfectly... except for one thing. When I send something it says that I sent it one hour ago. For example, if I send a snap on snapchat it would say that I sent it one hour ago when I clearly sent it in that moment. Does anyone know how to fix this? Its something I could live with but I just dont like to not be accurate with my time. Thank you

Comment: Eastern Daylight Time is correct if you live somewhere that observes daylight saving time. Eastern Standard Time is for the fall and winter, EDT is for the spring and summer (i.e. right now). Do you have a SIM from somewhere that observes DST, perhaps?

Comment: Nexus 4 running Android 4.3 JB. I have a similar problem. I set my time zone to auto, and all is well. But every so often -- a few times a week or so -- the phone just reverts to "non-auto" time zone, which changes the time display to something way off. no idea why this is happening. Happened too often, and too many actions requires for it to be a pocket-button-mashing event.